# Usage of `;` in compound commands

Tags: bash

The syntax of the `for` command is:

```
for name [ [in [words ...] ] ; ] do commands; done
```

The syntax of the `case` command is:

```
case word in [ [(] pattern [| pattern]...) command-list ;;]... esac
```

The `select` construct is Bash's extension to POSIX. It allows the easy generation of menus. It has almost the same syntax as the for command:

```
select name [in words ...]; do commands; done
```

The syntax of the `{...}` command is:

```
{ list; }
```

Questions:

1. why are the clauses in the `case` command separated by `;;` rather than `;` which is used in the other commands?
2. In the `for` and `case` commands,  when the `in` part is ignored, why are the following `;` and `;;` also ignored instead of remaining?

   By contrast, in the `select` command, `;` isn't ignored when the `in` part is ignored.

   Note that in the `case` command `in` isn't ignored with the following part, while in the `for` command it is. Are they arbitrary inconsistent designs of POSIX shells?
3. What kind of tokens are `;` and `;;` used in compound commands?

   In a command list (opposed to a compound command), `;` is a control operator.
4. In the `{ list; }` compound command, why must there be a `;` between `list` and `}`? Is `}` considered a clause, and is `{ list` also a clause? Must clauses in a compound commands be separated by either `;` or a newline?
   Further reading [to my previous question and Homer's reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267714/674), where I asked "Why do we need a semicolon instead of a whitespace for seperating the words?", given that "the semicolon and whitespace are both shell metacharacter",

Note:

I also would like to list the syntax of `while`, `until`, and `if` commands, but I think they behave similarly to the `for` command, in terms of the usage of `;`.

Comment: In the case of *case*. You can have multiple commands in a case claus, thus to terminate it you have `;;`. I.e. `foo) bar; baz;;`

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *In the for and case commands, when the in part is ignored ...*? The in part can be *omitted* in a for statement, is that what you mean? In a case statement, the in is required.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks. What I meant is the part following `in`.  I don't understand why  `;;` or `;` are  omitted together with the part following `in`. I assume a compound command is made up of clauses which are separated by `;` or `;;` (for `case`)

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for pointing out `;` is optional for `for`.  `case` is unlike `for`: `;;` is omitted not optional when the part following `in` is omitted.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for the links. Is the shell in the second link an old version of dash, or bash?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37272/discussion-on-question-by-tim-usage-of-in-compound-commands).

Comment: Tim, you've been a member for a few years now. You should really have understood that asking multiple questions in a single post is bad practice and the very definition of too broad.

Comment: Questions and answers can be conducted at multiple levels: principles and big pictures (which cover various specifices), or specifics. Multiple questions in a post are not necessarily loosely unrelated.  So I never clearly understand the "too broad" closing reason. @terdon

Comment: @Tim you are asking 4 separate questions and have even numbered them as such. Each requires a separate answer, or an answer broken into separate pieces. This is precisely what we want to avoid. We want specific questions with specific answers.

Comment: Sometimes I am not sure if there is a principle behind multiple specifics. That is why I list them together. @terdon

Comment: Next time, please break this sort of thing into separate posts. You can link to them if you feel your question would benefit from the context, but separate each question into its own post.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the part about `;;` vs. `;` in `case` statements, consider that it would be impossible to write a one liner command that would have multiple commands run in a single branch of a case statement if `;` terminated a particular branch.

You could still do it by using a multi-line command, but designing the shell grammar that way would *require* multiple lines, and there is nowhere else in shell grammar where multiple lines (newlines) are unavoidable.  Using `;;` for case switches in the shell design allows for greater flexibility when writing code.

---

To contrast `case` with `for`, `while`, `until` and `if`—all of those commands follow `list` with a specific reserved word in every use case.  (`then`, `elif`, `else`, `fi`, `do`, `done`)

`case` on the other hand follows a list with a "pattern", which could be *anything*—the desired pattern could happen to also be the name of a valid command.

Comment: Thanks. For `{ list; }`, also see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267714/674

Comment: @Tim, you don't need a space after the `;` by the way.  `{ list;}` works just fine because `;` is itself a metacharacter.

Comment: Do the `for`, `while`, `until`, `if` compound commands not allow multiple commands (separated by `;`) in a clause? If they do, how do they do without using `;;`?

Comment: @Tim, did you try to set up an example?  A `case` statement has *multiple* branches; *each* needs to be able to have compound commands.  `;;` ends the whole conditional branch of the `case` switch.

Comment: My last comment isn't about the `case` command, but the `for`, `while`, `until`, `if` commands.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic building block is a "simple command" (LESS=+/'Simple Command' man bash)

> Simple Commands
>         A  simple command is ..., and terminated by a control operator.

Usually, a comma (;) is such control operator terminating a simple command.

In most of the lines you copied from the manual, the (;) is used as a terminating control character. For example, in:

```
for name [ [in [words ...] ] ; ] do commands; done
```

both `in words;`  and `commands;` may be "simple commands" terminated by `;`. In this simple example:

```
for w in $(echo "a b c"); do echo $w; done
```

Both `echo "a b c"` and `echo $w` are simple commands. The list generated by `echo "a b c"` is terminated by a `;` (to detect the end of the list).
Which is not a must, this works the same:

```
for   w in    $(echo "a b c")
do    echo $w
done
```

The only reason that the whole `[ [in [words ...] ] ; ]` is optional in a for loop is because in such case, the list of elements is the list of "positional parameters" (which could be set with `set`):

```
$ set -- *
$ # for name [ [in [words ...] ] ; ] do commands; done
$   for f                            do echo $f; done
```

If you apply this same concept of "simple commands" building "Compound Commands" most of your questions are in-necessary.

> 1. why are the clauses in the case command separated by `;;` rather than `;` which is used in the other commands?

To be able to detect the end of **several** simple commands ended by simple `;` characters.

```
    case b in ([a-d]) echo "yes"; cp filea fileb; rm filed; ;; esac
```

Or re-written for readability:

```
    case b in
        ([a-d])
                echo "yes";
                cp filea fileb;
                rm filed;
        ;;
    esac
```

> 2. In the `for` and `case` commands, when the `in` part is ignored, why are the following `;` and `;;` also ignored instead of remaining?

The use of in is not optional in the case clause.

> 2.2. By contrast, in the `select` command, `;` isn't ignored when the in part is ignored.

The part `[in words ...]` is terminated by a `;` when the list of words is provided by the output of a command (ls *), Exactly the same way as it is used in the `for` command.

> 2.3. Note that in the `case` command `in` isn't ignored with the following part, while in the `for` command it is. Are they arbitrary inconsistent designs of POSIX shells?

No, no inconsistency apart from the ones generated by an incomplete understanding of the commands.

> 3. What kind of tokens are `;` and `;;` used in compound commands?

"Control operator"(s) used to terminate one or several "Simple Commands".

> In the `{ list; }` compound command, why must there be a `;` between `list` and `}`?

No, there not "must be", this is a correct list:

```
[ 2 -lt 4 ] &&
{ echo "yes"
  echo "it is smaller"
}
```

"Look Ma!! No (;)"
 But some kind of metacharacter (the newline) needs to be used to make the `}` stand by itself.

Yes: `[ 2 -lt 4 ] && { echo "yes"; echo "it is smaller"; }` looks different.
But is exactly the same command.

Ignoring the part about clauses (a new word with its own list of details).
I did not count them, but more than 10 questions about `time`, builtin, words, tokens, etc. Will you get in a similar train of questioning here?

Have you finally got what is or is not a "Simple Command"?
Then you may think about "Compound Commands", and only then (after some serious thinking) some other issue.

Comment: Thanks. (1) You said the reason of using `;;` in the `case` command is "To be able to detect the end of several simple commands ended by simple `;` characters." Then can the `if` command and `for` command do the same thing, i.e. allowing several simple commands ended by `;`? If yes, how, given that their syntaxes don't use `;;`? (2) `for f in ls *; do echo $f; done` is an ill example. There should be no `ls` in it. So your claim that it is the reason for using `;` in `for f in ls *;` is wrong. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271427/words-in-for-name-in-words-do-commands-done/271428

Comment: @Tim The for example has been updated. But `for` does not do the same as `case`. Try `for w in $(echo "a b c"); $(echo "d e f" ); do echo $w; done`. The for loop can not process two lists (even if separated by `;`).