# `words` in `for name in words; do commands; done`

Tags: bash

In Bash, the syntax of the `for` command is:

```
for name [ [in [words ...] ] ; ] do commands; done
```

1. But this example works

   ```
   for f in ls *; do echo $f; done
   ```

   I think that `ls *` is a command and can't be used as `words`. Instead we should use `for f in *; do echo $f; done`, where `*` with filename expansion can be used as words. So why does the above example  work?
2. I thought that in order for `ls *`  to be used as `words`, we must
   use command substitution instead:

   ```
   for f in $(ls *); do echo $f; done
   ```

   but this example doesn't do exactly the same thing as the previous
   one. This one will list the content of sub directories, while the
   previous one only list the sub directories without listing their
   contents. Why is this difference between the two examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ls` is just a word and `*` gets expanded by the shell.

In your second example, the shell first expands the `*` and then `ls` is called to list the results.

Comment: Thanks. I got the first example from http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/271183/674, and didn't noticed `ls` is in the stdout output. Now I understand it is an ill example.