# Why do I need an `;` or newline in `echo hi| { cat; }`?

Tags: shell-script, posix

In bash and dash the examples

```
echo hi | { cat ; }
```

and

```
echo hi | {
cat
}
```

produce the intended result `hi`. However,

`echo hi | { cat }`

is a syntax error

```
$ sh -c "echo hi | { cat };"
sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")
```

This seems somewhat surprising to me. I did a little digging and looked at the POSIX specification for sh (http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html)

a brace group is defined as

```
brace_group      : Lbrace compound_list Rbrace
                 ;
```

And a compound list is defined as

```
compound_list    :              term
                 | newline_list term
                 |              term separator
                 | newline_list term separator
```

The following rules seem to suggest to me that `cat` with no newline should be a valid term (and hence a valid compound_list on its own)

A `term` can consist of just an `and_or`

```
term             : term separator and_or
                 |                and_or
```

An `and_or` can consist of just a `pipeline`

```
and_or           :                         pipeline
                 | and_or AND_IF linebreak pipeline
                 | and_or OR_IF  linebreak pipeline
```

which can consist of just a `pipe_sequence`

```
pipeline         :      pipe_sequence
                 | Bang pipe_sequence
```

which can consist of just a `command`

```
pipe_sequence    :                             command
                 | pipe_sequence '|' linebreak command
```

which can be just a `simple_command`

```
command          : simple_command
                 | compound_command
                 | compound_command redirect_list
                 | function_definition
```

which can consist of just a `cmd_word` or `cmd_name`, I'm not sure which `cat` would be in this context.

```
simple_command   : cmd_prefix cmd_word cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_prefix cmd_word
                 | cmd_prefix
                 | cmd_name cmd_suffix
                 | cmd_name
```

I'm not sure whether `cat` in the above example would be parsed as a `cmd_word` or a `cmd_name`, but it seems like it should at least be parsed as a `simple_command`, why is an explicit separator required in this context?

Comment: I was just thinking that this seems like a question that Tim could answer, and indeed one of his Q's has an answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267706/117549