# Bash: returning from braces

Tags: bash

```
user@sv7280:~$ return
bash: return: can only `return' from a function or sourced script
user@sv7280:~$ { return }
>
```

What's going on, what does the prompt `>` mean here, where does the `{ return }` take me?

Comment: `{ return }` doesn't define a function - it starts a command group whose first command is `return }` (the "closing" brace is passed to `return` as an - invalid, non-numeric - argument). See [Separator between command list and }](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267706/separator-between-command-list-and)

Comment: OK, I see, `>` indicated a syntax error, `{ return; }` would have been correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`>` is the `$PS2` prompt that the shell issues to tell you the command is not completed and it needs more input from you to complete it.

In bash, if you do:

```
echo }
```

You'll see it outputs `}`.

`{` is a keyword that starts a command group.

```
{ echo }
```

is the `{` keyword followed by our `echo }` from above, and the shell is waiting for the closing `}` keyword before it can start running it.

That `}` keyword must be separated from the previous command, with `;`, newline (or `&`, or even things like `{(echo)}`...).

Whether it's the `echo` or `return` builtin, from a *syntax* point of view, it makes no difference. So you'd need:

```
{ return; }
```

But still, that `return` is not called from within a function, so you'd still get that error.

To define a function, in Bourne-like shells, you still `funcname()` in front of a command. In the case of `bash`, the command can only be a compound command, such as `(subshell)`, `{ command group; }`, `for ...; do ...; done`....

So, you'd need:

```
myfunc() { return; echo not reached; }; myfunc
```

Or:

```
myfunc() for i in 1 2; do echo "$i"; return; done; myfunc
```

Beside functions, `return` can be called from sourced scripts, so if you wanted to be able to return from a group of commands without having to define a function, you could do:

```
source /dev/fd/3 3<< 'EOF'
  echo foo
  return 123
  echo not reached
EOF
```

Or you could use a subshell and use `exit` in place of `return`:

```
(
  echo foo
  exit 123
  echo not reached
)
```

(but of course, the commands run in a subshell environment)

In `zsh`, you could also use an anonymous function:

```
() {
  echo foo
  return 123
  echo not reached
}
```