# Bash requires extra closing braces to define function

Tags: bash

From [this site](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick), I got the following Bash function to resize images using ImageMagick:

```
smartresize() { mogrify -path $3 -filter Triangle -define filter:support=2 -thumbnail $2 -unsharp 0.25x0.08+8.3+0.045 -dither None -posterize 136 -quality 82 -define jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off -define png:compression-filter=5 -define png:compression-level=9 -define png:compression-strategy=1 -define png:exclude-chunk=all -interlace none -colorspace sRGB $1 }
```

After I enter the above and pressing `<Return>`, Bash issues the prompt `...>`  to indicate that the command is incomplete.  Pressing `<Return>` again doesn't make it go away.  I have to enter an extra closing brace `}` before I am returned to the standard Bash prompt.

I've done this before, and did not observe this behaviour.  **Can someone suggest how I may track down the cause?**

**Further symptoms**

I tried using `smartresize()`:

```
$ mkdir smartout # Create destination folder
$ smartresize C82A4D44-0A8B-4BBA-90DB-45F683B3D8E6rot.jpeg 2016 smartout

# Output from smartresize
mogrify: unable to open image '}': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/3537.
mogrify: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/562.
```

Obviously, the extra `}` is syntactically wrong, yet
according to Bash, I must enter it.

Comment: See [Separator between command list and }](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267706/separator-between-command-list-and)

Comment: Thank you, *steeldriver*.  That solved the problem. It's odd that I never encountered this problem in using this exact same code before on several occassions earlier this year.

Comment: Note that the [bash function](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/#bash-shell) in your link is split across multiple lines; in particular it has a line break before the closing `}`

Comment: Ah, OK.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: As always, shellcheck: it throws SC1083 and SC1056 on this. Also, `mogrify` reports it failed to open `}` as a file, because it gets passed as an arg.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Cygwin's package search doesn't yield any *shellcheck*.  I will keep it in mind for situations where I'm working with LInux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When enclosing [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) expression in `{ }`; you need to terminate with `;`, so:

```
smartresize() { mogrify -path $3 -filter Triangle -define filter:support=2 -thumbnail $2 -unsharp 0.25x0.08+8.3+0.045 -dither None -posterize 136 -quality 82 -define jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off -define png:compression-filter=5 -define png:compression-level=9 -define png:compression-strategy=1 -define png:exclude-chunk=all -interlace none -colorspace sRGB "$1"; }
```

Comment: Thank you, Gilles.  That solved the problem. It's odd that I never encountered this problem in using this exact same code before on several occassions earlier this year.

Comment: @user2153235 You might have used a newline before the final `}`, which would work as well.